# API key Public vs secret

Tags: api, codeigniter, rest, authentication

I am using codeigniter for building web apps, and we decide to implement [Phil Sturgeon Restful application](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2011/03/video-set-up-a-rest-api-with-codeigniter) with codeigniter supporting many kind of authentications like: Basic, digset and Public Api keys

**I am a bit confused with the following:**

- The tutorial supported the Api key as a public key only and that key need to be sent with every api call in order to identify the caller.
- In that way is this a secure way to interact with the Api server, What about if third-party could read one of the messages that sent to the server. Or do i need to create a new Api Key whenever a user logged in and disable this key whenever he is logged out and it would be act like an access token
- Also I found that there is a way that including a digital signature with every call signed with some secret number using two Api keys (Public and Secret) and if someone manages to read one of sent messages they won't be able to be figure out this secret from the signature.And I don't know how to implement this kind of authentication in the main time with **Phil Implementation**

Comment: you sign your message with your secret key. Or encrypt using server public key, or both.

Comment: This implementation doesn't have secret key. it just have Api key

Comment: I am a bit confusing about Api Key and Public & secret Keys and access token